# Filter array by nested property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": "abc123",
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name: "category1"
    },
    "otherField": "otherField1"
  },
  {
    "id": "abc234",
    "category": {
      "id": 2,
      "name: "category2"
    },
    "otherField": "otherField3"
  },
  {
    "id": "abc456",
    "category": {
      "id": 2,
      "name: "category1"
    },
    "otherField": "otherField3"
  }
]
```

I am trying to filter by the category name, but the console is saying `"Cannot read property 'name' of null"`.

This is my function:

```
const bars = d.filter(x => x.category.name === "category1")
```

I tried something like this:

```
cost f = { "id": 1, "name: "category1" }
const results = d.filter(x => x.category === f)
```

But it's only returning 1 result in the array.

Any help is greatly appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: `d.filter`, did you mean `data.filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve the problem of reading `name` property of `undefined`

```
const bars = d.filter(x => x && x.category && x.category.name === "category1")
```

Another solution if you're using lodash/underscore

```
const bars = d.filter(x => (_.get(x, 'category.name') === "category1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem in your array with a quote.

Besides, there is no need to use quotes for your property names.

Use this instead :

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "abc123",
    category: {
      id: 1,
      name: "category1"
    },
    otherField: "otherField1"
  },
  {
    id: "abc234",
    category: {
      id: 2,
      name: "category2"
    },
    otherField: "otherField3"
  },
  {
    id: "abc456",
    category: {
      id: 2,
      name: "category1"
    },
    otherField: "otherField3"
  }
]
```